# Count seats provided in a svg image

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, counting

I want to count the seats in an SVG image. The problem is that the image is a theater/hall and this theater has different blocks/sectors. Like here:
https://www.wien-ticket.at/en/shop/index.php3?shopid=263&setsession=86hbtra3lilao85mip5rl31om6d164&gotoperformance=143703

So here we have the theater and its blocks. No seats to count here, I found nothing needful for seat counting with the dev tools.

Let's assume I click on "Osttribüne Reihen 1-17" (englisch: east stand row 1-17) and then clicking on select your seat. Then I come to the overview where I can count the seats.

I have tried nothing so far, because I don't know how this is working. Normally I count through such ticket shops with the given URL. For example each block has its own URL, I fetch it go to it and count through the grey seats. On this page I have always the same URL. So when I click on a specific position in the svg image i am going deeper.

This is the start of the svg:

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" sodipodi:docname="WT saalplan halleD svg 24042018 wwe 01.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" version="1.1" height="830" width="850" id="svg3141" viewBox="0 0 850 830" style="width: 684.9px; height: 668.728px;">
 ...
</svg>
```

The "Osttribüne (1-17) has a  tag, which provides the following information:

```
<path id="polygon7-9" d="m 266.76366,530.47852 0,105.9 316.09996,0 0,0 0,-105.9 z" style="display: inline; fill: url(&quot;#adjacent-seats-available&quot;); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(68, 68, 68); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 0px;" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path>
```

I don't think anything usefull is inside here. The only useful thing I found in my opinion is the "id" in the def tools, when I check the "Select your seat" button

```
<button type="button" class="btn <!--btn-primary-->
btn-custom-primary btn-block  btn-seat-select text-uppercase"
data-block-id="635960" data-elem-id="gsectorO1">
                Select your seat
</button>
```

Maybe I can use this for anything.

So my main problem is: How do I come from the starting point (given URL) to the seat counts of a block. I don't know how to "connect" the `<path>`tag Osttribüne (Reihen 1-17), clicking on it, then click on the `<button>` "Select your seat" and then I come to a new particular site, where I could count the seats. Obviously my aim is to go in each block in the SVG image and count them. And I don't know how to connect each block, with the seats behind this block.

I don't even know which technique I should use. I think maybe it is a combination of XML and Javascript or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the seats in the SVG image is represented by a `<circle>` element.

You can tell the seat status - if you need that - by looking at the `data-simpleid` attribute.  Taken/unavailable seats look like this:

```
<circle cx="1679.6000000000001" cy="155.6" r="8" index_reihe="8" index_sitz="91" sitz_nr="9" style="fill: url(&quot;#taken-seat&quot;);" 
        data-simpleid=""></circle>
```

Available seats look like this:

```
<circle cx="114.4" cy="173.8" r="8" index_reihe="9" index_sitz="5" sitz_nr="95"             style="fill: rgb(218, 33, 239);" data-color="#da21ef"
        data-simpleid="2" data-complexid="105422" data-original-title="" title=""></circle>
```

Empty of unset `data-simpleid` means taken. A value of "1", "2" or "3" indicates the seat price.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not my problem. My problem is - because I only have the starting URL - how do I come (for example with Javascript) from the first layer (the complete theter, with the different blocks) to the second layer (when I click on a block and want to choose a seat) and then count the seats.